# KOMA-Script list of hooks

Tags: koma-script, hooks

I'm currently trying to find the chapter name with KOMA-Script and probably need a hook for that.

Is there a list with all the available hooks?
Does anyone have better suggestions to do this?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with chapter name and in which hook are you interested? The name hook which is used by babel or something like a layout hook?

Comment: By chapter name I mean the text after the number, so the title of the chapter. So I‘m looking for layout hooks to save the name/title of the chapter.

Comment: Why do you want to save the  name/title of the chapter?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your clarification in the comments into your question, so it is self-contained. Your question seems to ask two different things: (1) about your concrete problem and (2) about a 'list of hooks' in general. You may want to focus your question on only one of the two and remove the reference to the other.

Comment: In case you are more interested in saving the sectioning title, you may also want to show us a little [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) just so we can be sure we are talking about the same thing and the people that want to help you can get started more quickly. (An MWE is not required to understand your question, but it is a nice way to show that you care.) It also helps us if you explain *why* you want to do this, since some solutions are not suitable for all applications (this may turn out to be an XY-problem).